# gon gem is causing long load times

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I want to pass JavaScript an Array. I created it in the Rails controller and passed it to JavaScript with the gon gem. It works but it takes 5 or 6 second to load the page.

I'm wondering if there is an inefficiency or it's just that this gem is slow.

Here is my code:

```
class KinectsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_kinect, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /kinects
  # GET /kinects.json
  def index
    data = @@cprx.getImageData()
    pixeles = data.pixelData.bytes.to_a
    gon.vertices=pixeles
  end
```

Comment: Are you sure it is gon gem problem? What will happen if youc omment the last line out?

Comment: if I comment the last line (gon.vertices=pixeles) every thing is ok. I load the page in milliseconds. Thats why I think there is a problem with the gon gem. Its a large array because is an array of pixeles from a 640x480 image.